# Counting numbers only containing primes in given set of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

Suppose $\mathbb P$ is a set of primes, and more specifically I'm interested in infinite $\mathbb P$ but satisfying
\[ \sum _{p\in \mathbb P}\frac {1}{p}<\infty .\]
How can I evaluate
\[ \sum _{n\leq x\atop {p|n\implies p\in \mathbb P}}1\]
and in particular has this been done already somewhere?  If $\mathbb P$ has some size restriction, then it's possible to get asymptotics using sieve methods, but I want no such restriction.

The associated zeta function, if I've understood correctly, is the \emph {Burgess} zeta function
\[ \zeta _\mathbb P(s)=\sum _{n=1\atop {p|n\implies p\in \mathbb P}}^\infty \frac {1}{n^s}=\prod _{p\in \mathbb P}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}.\]
Now this may not have a meromorphic continuation (if I've understood some of the comments in https://arxiv.org/search/?query=A+Remark+on+Partial+Sums+Involving+the+Mobius+Functions&searchtype=all&source=header) but the question of the counting function above is much easier, right?

Comment: It’s not too hard to show that your quantity is $o(x)$. More generally, if the sum of the $1/p^{\alpha}$ converges, then the sum is $o(x^{\alpha})$ for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$. But I’m not sure how much further one can push without more information on the set of primes.

Comment: is there any chance of an asymptotic for it do you know?

Comment: I don’t know of anything specific, but I’ve been told that you may want to look at “sieving methods”.

Comment: ye, as i say in the post i thought they were suited only when we have size restrictions on the primes, but maybe not then i guess